# How to add get post link feature in my WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, button

How to add get post link feature beneath my posts in my WordPress website so that visitors can easily share that link wherever they want ... I need a dedicated button for that .... is it possible in WordPress? P.S. I don't want to copy from the browser url field.